# Qt4 File open error : No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to open an external text-based file, like this:

```
QFile inputFile("mytextfile.txt");
if (inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
{
    QTextStream in(&inputFile);
    while (!in.atEnd())
    {
        QString line = in.readLine();
        ..
    }
    inputFile.close();
}
else
{
    QString errMsg;
    QFileDevice::FileError err = QFileDevice::NoError;
    errMsg = inputFile.errorString();
    err = inputFile.error();
    qDebug() << errMsg;
    exit(1);
}
```

The external file location is next to source code. There is nothing that locking the text file.
But I'm always getting the following error message: `No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1):

The file being next to your source file is not relevant. 
What *is* relevant is what your *current working directory* is when you run the program.

What the *cwd* is depends on how you start the program. When started from a commandline/shell it'll be the directory you were in when starting the program. When running the program from a GUI it'll usually be some pre-defined dir like the desktop or your home dir. When running from your IDE it's usually the directory where your executable was placed during compilation (or wherever you want; it's usually configurable).

In any case, you can use `getcwd` to get the *actual* cwd during runtime. Then you can use that to locate your data file.